# Tensorflow error - tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/paperspace/nmt-chatbot/data/tst2012.from; No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow

I have been following the sentdex tutorial on a tensorflow chatbot, and on coming t train the chatbot using nmt, tensorflow repeatedly spits out -

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/paperspace/nmt-chatbot/data/tst2012.from; No such file or directory
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow, but nothing is working
The following is all the error messages I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 18, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=nmt.main, argv=[os.getcwd() + '\nmt\nmt\nmt.py'] + unparsed)
  File "/home/paperspace/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/paperspace/nmt-chatbot/nmt/nmt/nmt.py", line 539, in main
    run_main(FLAGS, default_hparams, train_fn, inference_fn)
  File "/home/paperspace/nmt-chatbot/nmt/nmt/nmt.py", line 532, in run_main
    train_fn(hparams, target_session=target_session)
  File "/home/paperspace/nmt-chatbot/nmt/nmt/train.py", line 229, in train
    sample_src_data = inference.load_data(dev_src_file)
  File "/home/paperspace/nmt-chatbot/nmt/nmt/inference.py", line 75, in load_data
    inference_data = f.read().splitlines()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 495, in read
    newdata = self.stream.read()
  File "/home/paperspace/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 119, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/home/paperspace/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 79, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/home/paperspace/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/paperspace/nmt-chatbot/data/tst2012.from; No such file or directory
```

The code in the train.py file is...

```
import sys
import os
import argparse
from setup.settings import hparams
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/nmt")
from nmt import nmt
import tensorflow as tf
# Modified autorun from nmt.py (bottom of the file)
# We want to use original argument parser (for validation, etc)
nmt_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
nmt.add_arguments(nmt_parser)
# But we have to hack settings from our config in there instead of commandline options
nmt.FLAGS, unparsed = nmt_parser.parse_known_args(['--'+k+'='+str(v) for k,v in hparams.items()])
# And now we can run TF with modified arguments
tf.app.run(main=nmt.main, argv=[os.getcwd() + '\nmt\nmt\nmt.py'] + unparsed)
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Please show your code that resulted in this error

Comment: Yes I will. I will add it to my original question above as the code is to long to put in a comment.